# Expire current build and upload new build to iTunesConnect with same App version and Build version

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

As iTunesConnect has introduced the new feature to expire the build which eventually remove the build from iTunesConnect. After doing that i wanted to upload the new build with same App version and Build version but getting below error

```
ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.2.8' for train '1.2.0'" at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset
```

Is it possible with new iTunesConnect?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Suppose you already have version number 1.0 in App Store then new version must be greater than 1.0.

**Refer following link for more details:** https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

**Version number and build number checklist**

Here are some things you can check when submitting a new build to the App Store. Making sure you have your version number and build number set properly will help you by avoiding having your app automatically rejected for having them improperly configured.

1. For each new version of your app, you need to invent a new version number. This number should be a greater value than the last Version Number that you used. Though you may provide many builds for any particular release of your App, you only need to use one new Version Number for each new release of your App.
   You cannot re-use version numbers.
2. You cannot re-use version numbers.
3. For every new build you submit, you will need to invent a new build number whose value is greater than the last build number you used (for that same version). For iOS apps, you may re-use build numbers when submitting different versions. For macOS apps, you must chose a new build number for every submission that is unique and has never been used before in any submission you have provided to the App Store (including build numbers used in previous versions of your app).
4. For iOS apps you can re-use build numbers in different release trains, but you cannot re-use build numbers within the same release train. For macOS apps, you cannot re-use build numbers in any release train.